# gnuplot multiple with same x-y scale ratio

Tags: gnuplot, axes

I found the solution provided here few years ago very useful:

[Gnuplot Multiplot Individual Plot Sizes + Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346183/gnuplot-multiplot-individual-plot-sizes-labels)

but what if I want to have the same scale ratio between x and y axes as in the left plot?

Best,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some script attempt with (un)wanted results. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . I understand you mean the same ratio between the lengths of  x- and y-axis, not the same (visual) ratio of x- and y-range, correct? Besides the same ratio, do you also want same absolute size of x- and y-axes?

Comment: Question answered? Any response and feedback would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want, check `help size` and the following 3 examples. `set multiplot layout 1,2` will split your canvas into two halfs and gnuplot will fill the halfs with the graphs depending on the options you give.

*Example 1:* `set size ratio -1` will try to make the same aperture ratio for the x-/y-ranges, i.e. the first plot will appear as a square (20:20 or 1:1), the second plot will appear as (100:20 or 5:1).

*Example 2:* `set size ratio 1` will force the graphs to have a ratio of 1:1. Since axis and/or tic label might need different amount of space, gnuplot's automargin will result in borders with different absolute size (but identical ratio).

*Example 3:* if you want same axes length ratio *and* same absolute subgraph size, you better use multiplot without layout, set all the margins to `0` and set the sizes and origins (and hence the ratios) yourself (check `help origin`, `help size`). Then you have to take care about enough margins for the labels.

**Script:**

```
### different sizes and ratios of multiplots
reset session

set size ratio -1
set multiplot layout 1,2
    set xlabel "one liner"
    plot x
    
    set xlabel "two\nliner"
    plot x**2
unset multiplot

pause -1

set size ratio 1
set multiplot layout 1,2
    set xlabel "one liner"
    plot x
    
    set xlabel "two\nliner"
    plot x**2
unset multiplot

pause -1

set size noratio
set multiplot
    set margins 0,0,0,0
    sizeX   = 0.4
    sizeY   = 0.8
    originX = 0.05
    originY = 0.17
    
    set origin originX, originY
    set size   sizeX,sizeY
    set xlabel "one liner"
    plot x
    
    set origin 0.5+originX, originY
    set size   sizeX, sizeY
    set xlabel "two\nliner"
    plot x**2
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Results:**

*Example 1:*

[image]

*Example 2:*

[image]

*Example 3:*

[image]